# How to read linux file on windows?

Tags: linux, windows

I install Linux on my Portable Hard Disk. But I can't read and transfer files to it on my windows computer.

The file system of /home is ext4. I tried ext2explore and paragon HFS+. They didn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Windows question.

Comment: this question does not clarifies info about details like filesystem, and it can be resolved.

Comment: What block device is /home mounted on? Is it a partition, LVM logical volume, encrypted device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the drive is formatted in ext4 or other UNIX based file system then your best for using is [this](http://www.paragon-drivers.com/extfs-windows/) driver.

**Note:** You will need to purchase the license for the driver.

Better solution would be take backup of your external drive and format it using NTFS which is supported in Linux using ***ntfs-3g*** package and windows has inherent support for it.

Refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows) for more information.